# Error authenticating proxy while running agent job

Tags: sql-server, proxy, ssis, permissions, sql-server-agent

I am trying to schedule a SSIS2014 package via SQL Server Agent job. Both SSIS and SSMS are running on my local machine in the same domain. I am running SSMS with the same user `Domain\Admin` which is the creator of the SSIS package. SSMS 32-Bit and SSIS 32-Bit are running on Windows 7 64-Bit machine. I can run the package within SSIS without problems.

Using Microsofts KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760 and tutorial video http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440760%28v=sql.100%29.aspx I tried a couple of methods (proxy, configuration file, EncryptSensitiveWithPassword) but none of them worked for me.

When I use a proxy account to run the job step, the following message occurs:

```
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Error authenticating proxy
`Domain\Admin`, system error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.). 
The step failed.
```

The proxy account uses the credentials identity `Domain\Admin`. Since the password fields for credential properties in SSMS cannot be left blank, I typed any password although my corresponding windows account has no password. So as mentioned above it's the same user account that created the SSIS package since `Domain\Admin` is stated in the CreatorName property of the SSIS package.

With this proxy, I tried to run SSIS jobs using the package ProtectionLevel's `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` and `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`. Running the package manually within SSDT without problems, but from SSMS agent job the same error message appears. I tried the package sources "File System" and, after importing the package to MSDB, "SQL Server" and "SSIS Package Store". But exactly the same error message appears with each method.

Task manager shows that SSMS is running in administrator mode. Using Windows Component Services I added DCOM permissions for `Domain\Admin` to start and activate "Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 12.0" from local. But the same error message appears. So in my opinion it's a problem with SSMS user account permissions (???) but unfortunately I don't know what exactly to do here. I tried the following:

In the system database MSDB (full path: `Databases / System Databases / MSDB / Security / Logins`) I assigned all available role memberships (Including db_ssisoperator, db_ssisltduser, db_ssisadmin) to `Domain\Admin`.

In server security (full path: `Security / Logins`) I assigned all available server roles. In the tab User Mapping, I assigned the MSDB database.

Still the same error message appears when I try to run the job. Does anybody have some ideas what I can try?

Comment: Is the proxy account enabled when you run this: SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysproxies

Comment: See accepted answer here:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20613/how-to-give-sql-server-job-owner-permission-to-proxy-a-credential

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I run `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysproxies´ I can see ´enabled = 1´ for this proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the hyperlink. I tried what is stated in that answer and checked the principals tab of my proxy. Indeed, the `Domain\Admin` account wasn't there. But when I add it, it will be deleted automatically. I think it's because members of the role `sysadmin` have automatically access to proxies, what is applicable here.